# My app keeps crashing when i open it

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I had added 2 spinners to my cricket scoring app and there are no compiler errors however my app keeps crashing on start. It was working fine when I added the first spinner but the moment I added the second spinner the app started to crash. Please help.

```
package com.example.visha.cricketcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private Spinner spinner2;

    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String value = text.getText().toString();
    EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String value2 = text2.getText().toString();
    private static final String[]paths = {"15", "20", "30"};
    private  final String[]paths1 = {value, value2};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths1);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
                break;
            case 1:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
                break;
            case 2:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                break;

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to implement `OnItemSelectedListener` to `MainActivity`

Comment: Yes but when I add it this error appears - Error:(15, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>) in OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Override `onNothingSelected()` method in `MainActivity`

Comment: Please edit your question's title to give some indication of the problem you're having.

Comment: I am a noob in this so how do i Override onNothingSelected

Comment: `@Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}`

Comment: where in my code do I add this

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Thanks for your help but I have edited this question and could you please take a look

Comment: Please guys I have edited the question and it would be a real help if you could answer my question

Comment: however there is something I need to change in the manifest but I don't know what\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing `this` in method like `setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` means you are passing reference of listener as class but you don't implemented listener, impalement  `OnItemSelectedListener` like following and try,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

Comment: Error:(15, 64) error: cannot find symbol class OnItemSelectedListener
Error:(42, 43) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnItemSelectedListener
Error:(46, 1) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: i have changed please check now,

Comment: I have edited my entire question could you please take a look

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `OnItemSelectedListener` to access the onItemSelected method.

Comment: How do I Override onNothingSelected() method in MainActivity

Comment: @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

Comment: I have edited my entire question could you please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must implement the interface `onItemSelectedListener` and override the method `OnNothingSelected`

## Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements onItemSelectedListener{ 
....
```

Then with the Mouse Cursor in the Main Activity let your IDE auto insert all the missing method implementations

Comment: how do you override rhe OnNothingSelected method

Comment: I have edited my entire question could you please take a look